# How to create dashed radius border just with css?

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to create a radius border but not with solid style but with dashed style.

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smey7/) which is in solid style, but I want it to be dashed style.

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px dashed;
    position: relative;
}
div:after{
    content: "";
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 15px;
    right: -29px;
    border-top: 2px dashed;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px dashed;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed;
    border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;
}
```

---

[image]

---

**Update:**

It's working in chrome and ie too but not in firefox, and I'm using firefox version 28.

Comment: it is dashed already, man.

Comment: check for after pseudo elements:)

Comment: hi, it's dashed only. do you mean dotted style .. please check the link for demo http://jsfiddle.net/smey7/2/

Comment: @C-link its already dashed.

Comment: agree @Renjith, it's dashed already.

Comment: check my picture in question...

Comment: Boss it's not as we see your link. in your fiddle it's dashed. all dashed. http://jsfiddle.net/8gmfm/

Comment: @mayankcpdixit oh! which version....???

Comment: Yupp, for me, too. In the fiddle it's all dashed, no solid parts at all.

Comment: Oh! yeah its dashed in chrome and ie but not in firefox... and I'm using version 28

Comment: @C-link Update your question with what browser and version this isn't working in.

Comment: Actually if you decrease the border radius its showing proper. You need something which will specify the width of the dash :)

Comment: oh! but this will damage my design

Comment: Than go for background image.  check this link http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

Comment: @SSS or you may lay a mask on top of it :) , via pseudo:before and @-moz-document http://jsfiddle.net/smey7/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your little boxe doesnt hold any content, you may use another pseudo element to create a mask.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/smey7/6/)**

```
div:before {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 15px;
    right: -29px;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px white, 0 0 0 5px white;;
    border:solid transparent 5px;
}
```

---

Actually, it would be better to only serve this to mozillas browsers :**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/smey7/7/)**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    div:before {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 15px;
    right: -29px;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px white, 0 0 0 5px white;;
    border:solid transparent 5px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it sounds like a bug in firefox :

[bugzilla 382721](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721)

Which means that you'll have to use an image or something to make it look as it does in Chrome.  Pretty annoying.

Try going for this lnk http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

Note that i can't vouch for whether it is definitely possible to achieve your desired effect using border-image, but it seems like it might be.

Comment: Try and provide a solutions for it. Not the reason for its not working.

Comment: Well my answer to the question is that you cannot provide a dashed border radius in Firefox because of this bug.  That is the correct answer to the question which was asked "How to create dashed radius border just with css?".  I do not understand your problem.

Comment: I got no problem. :) Just trying to help out our stuck friend

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of Firefox. Every type of round corner looks like a `border-style:solid`. For a better understanding you can check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/boncutdan/f5b59/1/) example.